# How do I use a graphical or text based EDITOR on linux based on logging in locally or remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, text-editors

I can set my EDITOR variable in my .bashrc to e.g. gedit, which is a nice graphical editor on ubuntu. But when I log in over PuTTY that editor will fail.

What is the best way to detect if I'm logged in and can run a graphical editor, or not, and set EDITOR appropriately??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ~/.xinitrc (or ~/.xprofile if X starts via a display manager):

```
export EDITOR=gedit
export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```

In .bashrc (or whatever user init file for your shell):

```
export EDITOR=emacs
export VISUAL=$EDITOR
```

I try to keep X related stuff out of my shell init files.

Answer (score 3):

... some fiddling ... this may be it?

```
if [ "$DISPLAY." == "." ]; then
 export EDITOR='vim'
else
 export EDITOR='gedit'
fi
```

Comment: Or you can check `$SSH_CLIENT`, but this approach will work when you'll login into a plain tty, too, so it's more flexible.

Comment: `if [ -z $DISPLAY ]`

Comment: @Dennis: why play with fire? `if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]]` in bash/ksh/zsh or `if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]` to be portable (or `if [ x"$DISPLAY" = x ]` if you're paranoid about buggy antique Bourne shells).

Comment: @Gilles: Because `-z` by definition knows how to deal with null and unset variables. However, you're correct insofar as it's better to have consistent habits.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks. I always use double brackets in Bash anyway. I never thought about the `-o` type of cases inside single brackets.